# For loop to find out solution?

Tags: c++

Problem:
How many times does it take for one person to carry all items? Person can carry 'carryWeight' kg of weight each time.

My solution:

```
int main()
{
int a = 40; // 1st item weight
int b = 35; // 2nd item weight
    int c = 20; // 3rd item weight

    int maxItemWeight = a; // Max weight item. 
    int times; // Times to carry all the items
    int carryWeight; //How much weight a person can carry at once
    cin >> carryWeight;


    if (maxItemWeight > carryWeight)
        cout << "It's impossible to carry all the items " << endl;
    else {
    if((a + b + c) <= carryWeight)
        times = 1;
    else if ((a+b) <=carryWeight && (a+c) <=carryWeight && (b+c) <=carryWeight)
        times = 2;
    else 
        times = 3;
    cout << "Times to carry all the items: " << carryWeight << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Solution is simple, but if you have to add more variables it gets complicated. Is it possible to use an array and some loop to get a solution for any number of variables?

Comment: Please describe the problem. Just pasting in code and saying "this is simple" will get your question removed.

Comment: This looks like a Knapsack Problem. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: I don't get what you're asking...? I second that @aardvarkk

Comment: My solution is simple, but it's not good. I'm asking for some hints. How to make this code universal by using for loop or something.

Comment: @user3088184 The folks here are not understanding the problem. For anyone who's seen it before, it's obvious what the idea is, but apparently, given just your question, it's not obvious to everyone. (Possible suggestion for wording for one specific set of items: "Someone can carry 60 kg. That person has to move a total three items, of 40, 35, and 20 kg. If multiple items can be combined and carried in one go, how many runs are needed?")

Comment: Ty aardvarkk. I'll check that out.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like you have working code and are asking how to make it better. We have another Stack Exchange website for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are asking if you can use an array to allow for any number of "items" to be carried.  The answer is yes:

```
std::vector<int> item_weights;
unsigned int item_count = 0;
std::cout << "Enter item count:  ";
std::cin >> item_count; // I'll leave the error checking to you to implement
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < item_count; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Enter weight for item " << (i + 1) << ":  ";
    unsigned int w = 0;
    std::cin >> w; // again error checking should be added
    item_weights.push_back(w);
}

// insert code to retrieve maximum weight that can be carried here

unsigned int max_weight = std::max_element(item_weights.begin(), item_weights.end());
unsigned int total_weight = std::accumulate(item_weights.begin(), item_weights.end(), 0);

// insert your code to determine the number of times it would take to carry all items here
```